# How do I add a heroku deployhook:email using API?

Tags: api, heroku

I have been able to add a deployhook (for email and IRC) using the heroku cli (sdk). I would like to be able to add or update the email values (receipient etc) using the API. Is this possible? When I try to curl request to add a hook I get an error message noting the need for extra data: receipient, body, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a bit more detail about the different arguments here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploy-hooks#email

Once you know what values you want/need you should be able to send it using this:

`curl -n -g -X POST 'https://api.heroku.com/apps/MYAPP/addons/deployhooks%3Aemail?config[recipient]=me@example.com&config[subject]="MYAPP%20Deployed"&config[body]="{{user}}%20deployed%20app"'`

The arguments:

- -n reads credentials from netrc (this should be set by the toolbelt/cli)
- -g tells it to not try and interpret the [] and {} in the url
- -X POST sets it to be a POST rather than get request

Beyond that it was just a matter of encoding the params properly. I believe of those values recipient is the only required value (and the others have reasonable defaults).

You can only have one deployhook per type and they don't appear to allow updates. So if you need to change it, you'll want to remove the old one and then add another with the updated attributes. You can remove the old one like this:

`curl -n -X DELETE 'https://api.heroku.com/apps/MYAPP/addons/deployhooks%3Aemail'`